# How to get a list inside an element in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have the following structure in Firebase:

```
"surveys" : {
"-Kq2r56mEoZ0LDBbi47W" : {
  "name" : "Survey 1",
  "questions" : [ {
    "name" : "Question 1"
  },{
    "name" : "Question 2"
  },{
    "name" : "Question 3"
  } ]     
}
```

Here is the corresponding Java class **Survey.java**:

```
public class Survey {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();

    public Survey(){}
   // Getters and setters
   ...
}
```

In my Activity I try to get the survey element like this:

```
final DatabaseReference surveysReference = database.getReference(FirebaseReferences.SURVEY_REFERENCE).child(currentId);
surveysReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        SurveyDao survey = snapshot.getValue(SurveyDao.class);
        surveyList.add(survey);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());

    }
});
```

But I keep getting errors because the structure is not correct. 
How can I get my "questions" list and save it in my Survey object?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ for create response class from json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Questions** in your **Survey** should be :

```
List<Map<String, String>>
```

instead of :

```
List<String>
```

You can also create a **Question** class :

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Question {

    public String name;

    public Question() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(Question.class)
    }

    public Question(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

and it will be :

```
List<Question>
```

Check the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write).

Answer (score 0):

in your respone Survey contain another object i.e.Kq2r56mEoZ0LDBbi47W that via your Survey  class like

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Surveys {

@SerializedName("-Kq2r56mEoZ0LDBbi47W")
@Expose
private Kq2r56mEoZ0LDBbi47W kq2r56mEoZ0LDBbi47W;

public Kq2r56mEoZ0LDBbi47W getKq2r56mEoZ0LDBbi47W() {
return kq2r56mEoZ0LDBbi47W;
}

public void setKq2r56mEoZ0LDBbi47W(Kq2r56mEoZ0LDBbi47W kq2r56mEoZ0LDBbi47W) {
this.kq2r56mEoZ0LDBbi47W = kq2r56mEoZ0LDBbi47W;
}

}
```

and Kq2r56mEoZ0LDBbi47W class contain question list

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Kq2r56mEoZ0LDBbi47W {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("questions")
@Expose
private List<Question> questions = null;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public List<Question> getQuestions() {
return questions;
}

public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
this.questions = questions;
}

}
```

and question class is:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Question {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Survey class is like this :

```
public class Survey {
   private String name;
   private ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();

   public Survey(){}
   // Getters and setters
   ...
}
```

Then your firebase structure should be like this :

```
"surveys" : {
   "-Kq2r56mEoZ0LDBbi47W" : {
        "name" : "Survey 1",
        "questions" : [ 
             {
              0 : "Question 1"
             },{
              1 : "Question 2"
             },{
              2 : "Question 3"
             } 
        ]     
}
```

Remember arrayList or list, is like a Map, but using an `integer` as index. And it start from 0